# Javafx apply filter on pixels of an image

Tags: image-processing, javafx

I am under way to write a photo management application github.com/lanthale/photoslide and therefore I want to implement basich image enhancement effects. My basic filter (convert to greyscale) is working but if I move the slider it always takes 1s or 2s before the update is taking place.
How can I implement a version which updates the image instantly ?

Here is the code of the filter:

```
public class SampleFilter {

private final Image image;

public SampleFilter(Image img) {
    this.image = img;
}

public Image filter(double redLimit, double greenLimit, double blueLimit) {
    if (redLimit == 0) {
        redLimit = 0.2162;
        greenLimit = 0.7152;
        blueLimit = 0.0722;
    }
    PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
    int height = (int) image.getHeight();
    int width = (int) image.getWidth();
    WritableImage filteredImage = new WritableImage(pixelReader, width, height);
    PixelWriter pixelWriter = filteredImage.getPixelWriter();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int pixel = pixelReader.getArgb(x, y);

            int alpha = ((pixel >> 24) & 0xff);
            int red = ((pixel >> 16) & 0xff);
            int green = ((pixel >> 8) & 0xff);
            int blue = (pixel & 0xff);

            int grayLevel = (int) (redLimit * red + greenLimit * green + blueLimit * blue);
            int gray = (alpha << 24) + (grayLevel << 16) + (grayLevel << 8) + grayLevel;

            pixelWriter.setArgb(x, y, gray);
        }
    }
    return filteredImage;
}
```

}

Here is the code to call the filter:

```
apertureSlider.valueProperty().addListener((o) -> {
        executorParallel.submit(() -> {    
            if (shownImage==null){
                lightController.getImageView().setCache(true);
                shownImage=lightController.getImageView().getImage();
            }
            SampleFilter sf=new SampleFilter(shownImage);
            double val=apertureSlider.getValue();
            Image filteredImage = sf.filter(val, val+0.5, val-0.20);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                lightController.getImageView().setImage(filteredImage);
            });                
        });
    });
```

Comment: a) profile to find the bottleneck b) do all to fix the bottleneck c) if its unfixable, make it appear quicker (I suspect - but that's a wild wild guess without profiling! - part of the problem might be that you trigger a new filtering process too often, check for isChanging) Also note: you __must not__ access a node in an active scenegraph (nor any of its properties) off the fx application thread (which might or not be the case, depending on whether or not the lightController's imageView is active)

Comment: I suspect it is the pixelReader.getArb and pixelWriter.setArgb calls that are slowing you down.  It would be better to read everything into an array, process the array (possibly in place, possibly making a new copy, depending on the needs of the algorithm) and then setting all the pixels at once by passing the entire destination array to the pixelWriter.

Comment: Thank you. I managed now to use the array's which is the way to speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hints about manipulating the pixel array and not the argb values. I have now a version which works almost. With almost I mean it is now possible to move the slider and the image is changing during moving the slider. Left is a little lag but I think it is possible to remove that also with some background task or other optimizations.

Here is the faster version:

```
public class SampleFilter {

private final Image image;
private WritableImage filteredImage;
private int[] buffer;

public SampleFilter(Image img) {
    this.image = img;
}

public Image filter(double redLimit, double greenLimit, double blueLimit) {
    if (redLimit == 0) {
        redLimit = 0.2162;
        greenLimit = 0.7152;
        blueLimit = 0.0722;
    }
    PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
    int height = (int) image.getHeight();
    int width = (int) image.getWidth();
    if (buffer == null) {
        buffer = new int[width * height * 4];
        pixelReader.getPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), buffer, 0, width * 4);
    }
    filteredImage = new WritableImage(pixelReader, width, height);
    PixelWriter pixelWriter = filteredImage.getPixelWriter();
    int[] targetBuffer = new int[width * height * 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        int pixel = buffer[i];
        int alpha = ((pixel >> 24) & 0xff);
        int red = ((pixel >> 16) & 0xff);
        int green = ((pixel >> 8) & 0xff);
        int blue = (pixel & 0xff);

        int grayLevel = (int) (redLimit * red + greenLimit * green + blueLimit * blue);
        int gray = (alpha << 24) + (grayLevel << 16) + (grayLevel << 8) + grayLevel;
        targetBuffer[i]=gray;
    }
    pixelWriter.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), targetBuffer, 0, width*4);
    return filteredImage;
}
```

}